# product grid renderer multiselect attribute value

Tags: grid, ce-1.9.0.1, multiselect-attribute, product-grid

Following this [tutorial](http://magentoforall.blogspot.fr/2013/05/magento-display-multi-select-attribute.html), I try to get values of multiselect attribute in a product grid.

Products have some selected values for this attribute and the 'filter_condition_callback' for this column work.

In the renderer I use below code but in the grid I get an empty list.

I hope someone can help.

```
public function render(Varien_Object $row) {

    $colors=explode(',',$row->getColors());
    $suppstr="";
    if(count($colors)>0)
    {
        $suppstr="<ul>";
        foreach($colors as $value)
        {
            $attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'colors');
            if ($attribute->usesSource()) {
            $suppstr   .= "<li>".$attribute->getSource()->getOptionText($value)."</li>";
            }

        }
        $suppstr   .= "</ul>";

    }
      return $suppstr;    

}
```

Comment: did you try with removing `if ($attribute->usesSource()) {` condition?

Comment: not before your comment, I get the same result <td><ul><li></li></ul></td>

Comment: getSource()->getAllOptions() output all options

Comment: Try `var_dump($colors)` to check if you get data.

Comment: no i get an empty array

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you dont have set option values for your store.
Try,

```
$storeId   = 0; // Your Store Id
$suppstr   .= "<li>".$attribute->getSource()->setStoreId(0)->getOptionText($value)."</li>";
```

Comment: the grid block extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid and in _prepareCollection() I have Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

Comment: with your answer i get : Call to undefined method Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Table::setStoreId()